# Error de carga DLL

Tags: c#

Hola buenas  tengo este problema 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya he instalado en forma  de administrador el vjredist y también instale el net framework 1.1 
Algún consejo o otro programa que me falte instalar

Comment: esa libreria que intentas usar fue creada con .net ? puedes validar que tienes la referencia en el proyecto de la version que menciona el mensaje de error, esto lo valida en als propiedades de la referencia en el proyecto

Comment: Samuel esa Exception de FileNotFoundException la causa mas razonable es que estas intentando escribir el logger en un archivo que no esta creado o el directorio no es el correcto.
Lo que te comentan por ahí tambien puede ser posible algun Nugget que no este instalado pero me suena a que la ruta esta mal. Saludos,Jeff

Comment: ¿Qué tiene [tag:java] que ver en esto?

Comment: @jachguate vjslib es si no me equivoco la librería de Visual J#, un producto que por cierto está totalmente descatalogado

Comment: @Pikoh, pero visual J# no tiene nada que ver con Java, es un lenguaje más de .NET

Comment: @Marc J# está un poco en el limbo, era una implementación de Java que usaba .net. No era java pero si. O al reves.

Comment: @Samuel CM, prueba a modificar la referencia que tenga tu proyecto a vjredist, o directamente quita la referencia y vuelve a añadirla. Como consejo adicional, ve identificando las dependencias que tienes con J# y sustitúyelo por código C#, porque J# está descontinuado.

Comment: Puede ser por varias opciones, 1) el path al archivo dll es equivocado (revisa si el path es el correcto), 2) la dll no esta compilada para la version de .net que estas usando 3) faltan otras dll que necesita vjslib

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su apoyo , creo que el vjslib que instale estaba  mal , bueno esta es la ruta donde se tenia que descargar

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vstudio/bb188593